# New to C++ facing a segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I just started learning C++ and trying to port some PHP code at the moment.

I am getting a segfault from this piece of code :

```
class Color {

public:

    // Props
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
    int a;

    // Constructor
    Color (int r, int g, int b, int a) {
        this -> r = r;
        this -> g = g;
        this -> b = b;
        this -> a = a;
    };

    // Destructor
    ~Color () {
        delete this;
    };

    // Mix 2 colors
    void mixColor (const Color& c) {
        this -> r = (this -> r + c.r) / 2;
        this -> g = (this -> g + c.g) / 2;
        this -> b = (this -> b + c.b) / 2;
        this -> a = (this -> a + c.a) / 2;
    };
};
```

And in main file :

```
int main () {

    Color myColor (10, 20, 30, 40);
    return 1;
}
```

Any idea what causes it ?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. don't use `delete this;`, 2. `return 1;` -> `return 0;` or no return whatsoever

Comment: Yep, as Piotr said, `delete this` is your culprit. You don't even need a destructor on that class. I would suggest you get rid of it.

Comment: You will also definitely want to change your constructor so that the parameter names don't have the same names as your member variables. You have scoped the left-hand of the assignment to point to member variables, but its unclear to someone unfamiliar with the c++ standard what "r" will be interpreted as. It could be the parameter or the member variable. Perhaps alls your constructor does is assign the member variable to itself and not to the parameter, Although I'm not sure what the standard dictates or if this is undefined-behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the current answers.

The reason you can't be using delete in this case is that by not using the 'new' keyword you created the object on the stack, and it will be automatically destroyed when the scope it was created in is no longer relevant.

This is useful for an object such as the one you posted, since its small and more importantly, it isn't managing any sort of memory internally, which could lead to some memory leaks.

Also since everything inside the class is public, you might consider making it a struct.

Answer (score 1):

You should only call `delete` on things you allocated with `new`. You didn't allocate `this` with a `new`, so you shouldn't call `delete` on it.

Comment: Even if the OP _did_ use `new`, you shouldn't use `delete this`.